# How to highlight specific data points in a scatterplot (Excel) based on certain conditions?

Tags: excel, scatter-plot

Suppose I have a data with two sets of xy coordinates, one pair for the customer side and one pair for the vendor side (so in total, there should be four columns, two x's and two y's). We can call Xc for customer and Xv for vendor and vice versa for Y. I know how to make a plot in excel and overlay the two pairs of coordinates, but I am stuck on how to present such plot with specific data points highlighted with a different symbol/color based on conditional statements. For example, if any data points in Xc or Yv have coordinates outside of a specific range (think of them as outliers), I would like to flag such points on the scatterplot. I know one way is to filter out the points first and create it as a separate series then plot, but wonder if there is a more streamlined procedure in doing so as I need to make a template for future references. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "wonder if there is a more streamlined procedure in doing so"... not that I know of.

Comment: You could use VBA if you know how to macro - eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53511669/color-coding-stacked-bar-chart-using-keys/53514402#53514402

Comment: I'm not a huge expert on Macro but am willing to learn if it helps with my objective. I see the example you included is more of color coding the stacks rather than a scatterplot. If you have the time, I would like some pointers in setting up a macro regarding scatterplot.

Comment: Scatter plot works the same way: get the `Series` from the chart's `SeriesCollection`, and loop over the `Points` collection - each Point corresponds to one of your input values, so you can change its appearance based on the data value.  Use the macro recorder if you need help figuring out how to make specific formatting changes to the chart.  If you get stuck, post your code an explain the problem you're having. BTW I won't get notified of your comments to me unless you @ me i.e. @TimWilliams